# MySQL Load Data Infile (CSV) : replace/remove vertical tabs

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, notepad

When using LOAD DATA INFILE to load a csv file with CHARACTER SET latin1 (table also encoded as latin1) all vertical tabs are displayed as '□'.
Neither replacing 'u000b' nor '\v' worked.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'database.csv'
INTO table taxa
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(columns1...@column6...column19)
SET @column6 = REPLACE(@column6, '\u000b', '\t')
```

When I convert the table to UTF8 and import that with 'UTF8' specified, I get an error stating *"Invalid utf8 character string:..."* in the first field where a \v is coming up.

Notepad++ shows me a 'VT', so I know it's a vertical tab with escape char '\v'. Replacing it with Excel(where it shows up as '□') or NotePad did not work so far.

Printing it to the frontend of my WebApp shows:

```
'u000b' for \v` 
'u001d' for a Group Seperator`
```

**Question:**
How to remove these little f*** - Could be even done before importing them, but I couldn'T manage that either.

Comment: To remove them before importing the file, you could use *tr* or *sed*, or write a short script in awk, Python or other language of your choice.  *tr* is designed to do exactly what you want, but you'll need to get a Windows version (the GnuWin32 CoreUtils has it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Way easier than I would've ever thought:**

NotePad++ let's you search for unicode characters as well. 
Instead of `\v` I used [\u000b](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+000b) to search and replace the character. Same for the GS symbol [\u001d](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+001D)

Make sure to set the **search mode to *'extended'*** if you wan't to use unicode symbols.